# Tools for working with OpenShot project files

Tags: video-editing

I have a lot of videos which I want to combine into a single one with the help of OpenShot. The video's filenames contain a timestamp which I would like to show in the single video for each individual sub-video so that the viewer knows when the video was shot.

To help me with that task, I wrote a Java tool which would create the needed SVG files which are used by OpenShot and which also creates the OpenShot project file (which is simply JSON) which I can open in that program to finish the project.

I'd like to know if there are already other tools which create OpenShot project files to merge a lot of videos. Should:

- be open-source
- could be a command line tool
- produce OpenShot project file
- maybe an option to blend the videos for a defined amount of time

Edit: I've been also looking for a way to interact with OpenShot via Command Line or via scripting. But I guess there is nothing such for now. I've only found an old reference to [`openshot-renderer`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/openshot-render.1.html).